# SQL Server 2005 nested views - strategy for unentaglement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a reporting web application that graphs information based on aggregations done in a series of nested sql views (3 levels deep). The last nested view is called from a stored procedure within the entity framework code. The performance penalty of this has begun to take its toll, as it struggles to get data and times out:

In Sql profiler there's 360,000+ reads and CPU @ 28313.  In addition, I can't even open the third level view in SQL without timing out.

The first view simply gathers data from the several tables and aggregates. The second performs calculations on this data such as date differences, time zone adjustments, and averages. The third finalizing these calculations and presents a summary of the required data. The third view is the one I query from.

What is a good strategy for untangling nested views, in general? Specifically if you have calculations that need to be done in SQL server, but can only be done once data has been combined into a certain level, what's a better strategy than nested views?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You have very little concrete information in your question, making it hard to answer.  Have you done any profiling to see where the biggest bottlenecks are in your queries?

Comment: Does the view have to display real time data? One approach is to stage the data after calculations nightly into a table that your report pulls from.

Comment: Yea I struggled on whether to ask this question here but figured I'd try anyway. I have tried profiling and it definitely points to the stored procedure that calls the final view (huge number of reads, cpu)...but not much more to go on to change.

Comment: **If** you meet certain criteria, it's possible that the first view could be turned into an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). This would maintain a copy of the aggregated data (and SQL Server is responsible for maintaining it based on the original table), which is *probably* where most of the cost is.

Comment: @kdy, thanks. The view should always have the latest data so perhaps that's an option. I'm not 100% sure how to set that up, i can research it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include any view as a subquery, however, I doubt that in itself will help performance in this case. It will enable you to look at parts of the views and possibly put any shared parts into table variables or temporary tables.

If you could share more information, that might help.

I advise you:

1. inline those views, so you've got it all in front of you
2. cut it down, bit by bit, to see where the (uncompiled!!) performance issues are.
3. fix the performance issues
4. hope that the performance issues are in the same place once it is compiled.

Comment: Thanks @penguat. I anticipated a general cut down approach might be needed, and im interested in using the temp table option. I'm not sure what other information would be good to provide, let me know what would help?

Comment: example code generally helps - things like functions in the views can slow you down a surprising amount, but won't be spotted unless you mention it, or paste the code into your question.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the estimated / actual execution plans?